# Understanding Airpods Pro pairing behaviour

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth, airpods

I got a pair of Airpod Pros last month (Sep 2021). I paired them with my phone initially, but noticed quickly that this means they automatically pair with my MacBook Air as well. For a while using both felt smooth and I had no trouble, but in the last week or so it has suddenly started feeling janky.

My main annoyance is that when I have them paired to my laptop and I'm listening to music (on Spotify), sometimes even just picking up my phone and looking at the locked screen (which FaceID unlocks) will switch the pairing to the phone and my music stops, and I have to manually click at things for a while to get them back to the laptop and the music playing again. I think this happens when some other audio app is on top of the phone (say if I listened to podcasts on the phone earlier).

Can anyone explain the logic to how the Airpods decide which device they should be paired to? And is there a way to stop them jumping to my phone by their own decision even in the middle of music listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself that the simplest fix to the jumping was to switch the pairing mode from "automatic" to "when last connected to this device" in the AirPods' settings on both devices.

I'm still not entirely clear on the logic of how the "automatic" pairing decides where to connect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common race condition and depends highly on your setup and devices in the vicinity of AirPods. On my Mac, even if AirPods are connected to my iPhone, they will switch to my Mac once it is booted up.
In my case, it is the system Sound of Mac, that wants to play and searches for the nearest output device